# Cannot pass artifacts between jobs in GitLab CI/CD

Tags: git, docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a GitLab project and my `.gitlab-ci.yml` looks like this:

```
stages:
  - build
  - deploy

image: registry.gitlab.com/myuser/myproj/ubuntuxenial:v1

before_script:
  - cd /home
  - mkdir docker
  - cd docker
  - git clone "https://xxx@github.com/myuser/myproj.git" repo
  - cd repo

render_site:
  stage: build
  artifacts:
    name: "$CI_JOB_NAME-$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME--$CI_JOB_STAGE-$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME"
    expire_in: 1 week
    paths:
      - home/docker/repo/
  script:
    - Rscript build.R

...
```

I have provided the essential parts of the file in the context of this issue. As you can see, this automation is intended to do the following:

1. Clone a repository.
2. Invoke a build command inside the repository (I am using R). This step will generate some output files in the repository folder.
3. Make sure to publish artifacts, I want to publish the content of the whole repository `repo` folder.

**Note** I have set GitLab to use Docker images. I am using a Unix image I have uploaded in my registry.

#### Problem

The issue happens in the first job: `render_site`. Everything goes fine, the commands are executed and all builds fine. However, the last line in the log for that task is:

```
Uploading artifacts...
WARNING: home/docker/repo/: no matching files      
ERROR: No files to upload
```

---

#### Troubleshooting

I understand the issue is in the path I provide in `.gitlab-ci.yml`. I have tried the following:

- `home/docker/repo/`
- `/home/docker/repo/`
- `repo/`

Nothing works. This path that we specify, what is it relative to??? The [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#artifactspaths) mentions:

> You can only use paths that are within the project workspace.

What does it mean? I am creating a container every time I push and I `cd` into different directories in the commands I specify in `.gitlab-ci.yml`, so what is the *project workspace* the documentation mentions?

Comment: remove the first three lines of your `before_script`; path in artifacts should be `repo/` then

Comment: I just got it... Wow it was a bit cumbersome to find: [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pipelines/job_artifacts.html)

Comment: @ensc: Actually you should post the answer because your comment explains why this was failing... Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. My question clearly came as a lack of understanding of GitLab and how a runner works. What I was missing  is the fact that the runner, after creating a container out of the specified Docker image, will actually create, in the container, a folder with the commit.

#### Useless cloning

Therefore what I have in `before_script` is completely useless. And thanks to @ensc for pointing that in comments.

#### Project path

Coming to the question, the *project path* is exactly the directory created in the container where the repository is cloned at the specified commit.